# How to install and connect DataStax Driver for PHP Apache Cassandra local server with XAMPP in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, cassandra, datastax-php-driver

I am starting development of Cassandra databases and I wanted to start using the PHP driver DataStax.

I followed the installation guide https://github.com/datastax/php-driver and it appears to have been installed properly. I want to test my local server xampp and the connection is not being made properly. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS as my development environment.

Comment: Where is your PHP code, what have you done so far, did you check if your cassandra has been installed, have you started with the sample php code.

Answer (score 1):

The specific error message you are getting would be helpful.

Some tips:

- Make sure you are using Cassandra 2.0 or 2.1
- Make sure you are connecting to the right ip
- Make sure you are connecting to the right port

Example code to connect, with ip and port:

```
$cluster = Cassandra::cluster()
->withContactPoints("$ip")
->withPort(9042)
->build();

$session = $cluster->connect('system');
```